# Where is CP Message stored?

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-note-2

Today I got a message from my carrier. My phone (Galaxy Note 2) opened it in a screen titled 'CP Message' (I don't know if this was another  app). I installed the file that my carrier sent to me. After I closed it, I could not find it anymore. Where is it? How can I find it again?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go over to your Messaging app, press the options button/menu button (depends on the device). A short list will pop-up including options like Search, Drat Messages, Delete, etc. One of these options should say 'Configuration Messages' or something similar. This is where the CP messages you receive are stored. I'm not sure as to what purpose they serve (they seem to vary from lists of MMS to Browser settings), but that's where all of them are.

Answer (score 2):

Open Messages, tap the Options button, and then select the first option from top in the list which is "Configuration messages". In this way, you will be able to see all the configuration messages.